# How to write a linq statement to check if a record exists then make changes to it?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to write a linq statement so that if a record exists then make changes to one of object property else just leave it in it's previous state.

Please correct me on below, I am unable to form it?

```
ButtonColor = (from yy in cn.OrderDressings 
               where yy.OrderID == this.OrderID && yy.OrderItemID == this.ProductID 
               select yy.IsApplied == true) ? ButtonColor.Green : ButtonColor.Red
```

I was trying to use `FirstOrDefault`, `.Any` but didn't get success.

Comment: Why are you selecting `yy.IsApplied == true`? Was that meant to be another condition? And what is `ButtonColor`? It's not clear whether you're trying to change a property of the entity found by the query, or something else.

Comment: No that is not condition, but if i make no select it gives error so i make it that way.

Comment: I am trying to change the button color form database if a relevant record exist in the database, otherwise leave it.

Comment: What do you mean by "button color form database"? Your question is really unclear. It doesn't *look* like you want to change a property of the record, but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ButtonColor = cn.OrderDressings
                .Any(x=>x.OrderID == OrderID &&
                        x.OrderItemID == ProductID) ? ButtonColor.Green : ButtonColor.Red;
```

Comment: No that's not, although it seems to be working but if no record exist it will make the button color unaffected with no error?

Comment: @JonSkeet in fact, that's my guess about what the OP means, his code even doesn't compile.

Comment: I removed x.ispplied.

Comment: @NoviceToDotNet well, it doesn't even involve here but you still add it to your code? that makes me confused, I'm going to remove it too.